# RavenDB scripted patch from raven studio not run

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I try to run a patch request from Raven Studio on a large collection (over 8000000 documents) and the patch seems doesn't work, I don't see any changes on the documents but if I run it on a single document it works correctly. For a better test I created an equal collection with 100 documents and the patch works correctly.
In the Raven Studio under Status -> Running Tasks I can see my patch task running but without any effect.... any suggestions?

Thanks in advice.

Raven Studio version 3.0

Comment: Check the logs, it is possible that it is just taking a while to run it.

Comment: Thanks Ayende and ok it starts to run a few minutes ago it takes about 6 hours after start